# How group by two columns use pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have 3 columns - _a, _b, _c.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'_a':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3],'_b':[3,3,5,3,7,3,9], '_c':[10,11,12,13,14,15,16], 'a_b_3:[21,21,21,13,13,15,15]'})
df

    _a  _b  _c  a_b_3   
0   1   3   10   21
1   1   3   11   21
2   1   5   12   21
3   2   3   13   13
4   2   7   14   13
5   3   3   15   15
6   3   9   16   15
```

I need create column a_b_3 (sum all values _c for _b=3 by _a) use groupby from pandas. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the logic to fill 'a_b_3'? `df.groupby('_a')['_c'].transform('first')`

Comment: I need not first value. I need sum all values _c by _b=3 for all _a

Comment: So why, for example, the third row of `_c`, 12 is not included in any of the sums?

Comment: Because in the third row _b=5. Sum only _b=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df['a_b_3'] = df['_a'].map(df[df['_b'] == 3].groupby('_a')['_c'].sum())
```

Output:

```
   _a  _b  _c  a_b_3
0   1   3  10     21
1   1   3  11     21
2   1   5  12     21
3   2   3  13     13
4   2   7  14     13
5   3   3  15     15
6   3   9  16     15
```

***Explanation***

First filter down to only records that have _b equal to 3, then group by _a and sum to create a series.  Use that series to map back to _a values in the original dataframe.